# Error: ****@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, react-native-firebase

I have a simple firebase function that triggers on a file being uploaded to Firebase Storage. It was working on the non-main bucket, but once I changed it to listen to the main bucket I began receiving these error messages....

```
Error: *****@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.get access to *****.appspot.com/ff-icon-01.png.
```

The function is in the same project as the storage bucket.

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const gcs = new Storage();

import { tmpdir } from 'os';
import { join, dirname } from 'path';

import * as sharp from 'sharp';
import * as fs from 'fs-extra';

export const makeThumbnail = functions.storage
  .object()
  .onFinalize(async object => {
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(object.bucket);
    const filePath = object.name;
    const fileName = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const bucketDir = dirname(filePath);

    const workingDir = join(tmpdir(), 'thumbs');
    const tmpFilePath = join(workingDir, 'source.png');

    if (fileName.includes('thumb@') || !object.contentType.includes('image')) {
      console.log('exiting function');
      return false;
    }

    // 1. Ensure thumbnail dir exists
    await fs.ensureDir(workingDir);

    // 2. Download Source File
    await bucket.file(filePath).download({
      destination: tmpFilePath
    });

    // 3. Resize the images and define an array of upload promises
    const sizes = [64, 128, 256];

    const uploadPromises = sizes.map(async size => {
      const thumbName = `thumb@${size}_${fileName}`;
      const thumbPath = join(workingDir, thumbName);

      // Resize source image
      await sharp(tmpFilePath)
        .resize(size, size)
        .toFile(thumbPath);

      // Upload to GCS
      return bucket.upload(thumbPath, {
        destination: join(bucketDir, thumbName)
      });
    });

    // 4. Run the upload operations
    await Promise.all(uploadPromises);

    // 5. Cleanup remove the tmp/thumbs from the filesystem
    return fs.remove(workingDir);
  });
```

They have the same rules. Not sure what's up.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Security rules are no relevant when working with the server SDKs.  They are always bypassed.  Security rules apply to mobile and web sdk access only.  The error message is saying that the default service account for your project doesn't have the correct IAM permissions to access the file in question.  Not sure how to resolve that.  Did you make a change to the service account?

Comment: It looks like you're using the GCS sdk as opposed to the firebase sdk. Please ensure you're initializing your storage ref with your firebase app as described in the docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

Answer (score 2):

For someone else who runs into this issue.

The problem for me was that I were using the wrong project in my gcloud setup when uploading my functions. So I used one project in the firebase cli while using another project in the gcloud cli.

It worked for me when I deleted all the functions, change the gcloud cli project to the right one and then uploaded the functions again.